# Novice: testing fermat's theorem with simply user input(a,b,c,n) and if/else statement of whether the theorem holds?

Tags: python

I am a complete novice on my first week of programming (quit my job and am doing self-study coursework) and I am stuck on a problem in the book "Think Python: How to Think Like a Computer Scientist" in regards to simply testing fermat's last theorem. Posted below is the exercise:

*Exercise 3*

*Fermat’s Last Theorem says that there are no positive integers a, b, and c such that an + bn = cn for any values of n greater than 2.*

*Write a function named check_fermat that takes four parameters—a, b, c and n—and that checks to see if Fermat’s theorem holds. If n is greater than 2 and it turns out to be true that*

*an + bn = cn*

*the program should print, “Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!” Otherwise the program should print, “No, that doesn’t work.”*

*Write a function that prompts the user to input values for a, b, c and n, converts them to integers, and uses check_fermat to check whether they violate Fermat’s theorem.*

Here is my current code:

```
#user input is going to define the variables
def a():
    print raw_input("Please enter the value for 'a': ")

def b():
    print raw_input("Please enter the value for 'b': ")

def c():
    print raw_input("Please enter the value for 'c': ")

def n():
    print raw_input("Please enter the value for 'n': ")

#create function to check the theorem
def fermat_theorem_check(a,b,c,n):
    if (a**n) + (b**n) == (c**2):
        print "Holy Crap! Fermat was wrong!"
    else:
        print "Fermat is right!"

fermat_theorem_check(a,b,c,n)
```

Can you please explain what I am doing wrong? I don't want quick solutions, I want to know why my thought process is wrong and how I can understand the function's I am trying to use!
`fermat_theorem_check(a,b,c,n)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm working through the same book and wanted to see how others answered the question, I'm learning python. I'm using PyCharm 2.3

1. Define the variables and assign them from user input

   ```
   def check_fermat(a, b, c, n):

   print('There are no positive integers a, b, and c such that (a**n)(b**n) = (c**n) For any values of n > 2')

   a = int(input('Enter a number for a'))
   b = int(input('Enter a number for b'))
   c = int(input('Enter a number for c'))
   n = int(input('Enter a number for n'))
   ```
2. Check to see if it is true then the equation is wrong

   ```
   if (a ** n) + (b ** n) == (c ** n):
       print('Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!')
   ```
3. If it is false then the equation holds up

   ```
   else:
       print('No, that does not  work')
   ```
4. Assign the integer values from the user to the equation a, b, c, n

   `check_fermat('a', 'b', 'c', 'n')`

Answer (score 0):

Several things you should understand clearly:

- In Python, variables are defined with simple assignment: `a = 7`;
- the `print` is a statement that used only to show values in console;
- `raw_input` is a function that does two things: prints a message and *returns* a value from user;
- when a function returns a value, it can be assigned to a variable.

So, what's going on:

1. you are defining some functions — `a`, `b`, `c` and `n`;
2. inside these functions two things happen: `raw_input` gets a value from user, then the `print` statement prints that value. Note that your functions return nothing;
3. then, you are multiplying the functions. That won't work.

Also, you have a typo in this statement: `(a**n) + (b**n) == (c**2)`.

**Edit:**
Forgot to mention that you are not converting input values to integer. These are strings by default, and you can't do arithmetic with them.

Comment: Awesome I appreciate the support. I'm the type of person who wants to know the "why". I found the solution in a related topic but I don't like just copying people's work because I don't learn... So a few quick questions: Why are my functions not "returning" anything? I have learned about the "return" function but is that what it really is? Do I simply need to do a simple return statement in relation to each variable stating "return (variable") in each individual function?

Comment: so maybe indicate "return raw_input" in each function I created?

Comment: You can write `return` instead of `print` in these functions, and in would work, yes. But you also need to call the functions so they would work. If `a` is a function, then simply writing `a * 2` will throw an error. That's because `a` is like a door handle in this case: it doesn't contain what's behind the door, but lets you open it. And the function returns something, then when you open that door, this thing will just pop out of there. So, you should write `a()` to get that thing.

Comment: Oh wow... I think it all came down to the typo!!!!sorry for wasting everyone's time. I appreciate at least showing me the typo cuz I figured out a way to write it similar without a function for each... But now I'm going to test functions to better define the program! thank you for the help Meloman!